# Ubuntu Partition after installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I have already installed Ubuntu 12.04 with all the space allocated to just one drive in which Ubuntu is installed. I want to create partitions now.

I have a Bootable usb of Ubuntu 12.04. Do i need to burn GParted on that usb so as to make partitions. i have installed almost what i wanted and don't want to lose anything now.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Gparted on your computer from the software center and do the partitioning.

Comment: Gparted can't partition mounted disk.

Comment: You can use Gparted on your live usb.

Comment: please don't answer if you don't know anything about it or don't have the ability to elaborate ur answer.

Comment: I mean that Gparted is already present in your usb